# Protect Plesk login page from search engine eyes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, search-engine, plesk

I was wondering if would it be possible to protect the "https://www.DOMAIN.com:8443" URL from search engines listing perhaps using the htaccess to redirect the 8443 port from "DOMAIN" to elsewhere?

> **This is the  VZPP Plesk - Login Login to Plesk. Please enter your
>   login information. Username. Password.
>   Interface Language. User Default,
>   ENGLISH (United States), GERMAN
>   (Germany) ...
>   https://www.DOMAIN.com:8443/ -**

Comment: why not you try www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to use (if I've understood your question right)

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive"/>
```

And google about robots.txt... don't remember the syntax...

Comment: Didn't know. Never used Plesk. Well... Actually this is not a header itself - its only instruction for browser to do the same as if he got this header.

If this won't work - then only .htaccess, httpd.conf or something like ipfw.conf left, beacause there's no more layers to filter requests, only OS-firewall(s)-apache-php.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about using User-Agent detection with mod_rewrite [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-variable-fun-in-htaccess.html), how to setup your robots.txt for [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/03/speaking-language-of-robots.html), [Yahoo!](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/search/webcrawler/slurp-02.html), and [MSN/Live Search](http://blogs.msdn.com/webmaster/archive/2008/09/12/is-your-robots-txt-file-on-the-clock.aspx) - however, this all assumes sane and cooperative bots. There's little that can be done to protect against agressive, 'black-hat' bots.

Comment: Well, if they've cached it, they've cached it. You can use the Google trick below to find out when they grabbed the page.

http://lifehacker.com/5239562/display-the-date-a-web-page-was-published-in-search-results

Your best bet is probably to rename/move the 'control panel'. Also, make sure there are no 'inbound links' pointing there that bots might follow, or make sure you use the 'nofollow' pseudo-attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a `robots.txt` file containing the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and place it in `usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs`. Note that the location might vary depending on your installation.

Afterwards, verify that the file served at `http://my.domain.com:8443/robots.txt` points to this file and has the same contents. Also make sure that `http://my.domain.com/robots.txt` (the port serving your public site [usually the implied port 80]) *does not* point to the same file. If it does then you site won't be indexed at all.

This file will tell Google and other bots to not index the Plesk pages such as the login page. For more info about robots.txt check the [Google Help page about robots.txt](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-112hkfkbg6bjn&cbrank=2) or [Remove a page or site from Google's search results](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734). Additionally you may want to add your domain to the [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and check that the Plesk pages have indeed been removed by checking the [removals page](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals).